# drupal6 taxonomy cache, dropdown arrays & webform vs cck questions

Tags: drupal, forms, drop-down-menu, cck, taxonomy

1.is taxonomy do caching ? i do a form that user needs to fill his personal infomation and that include a street name, i wonder how to do it, in taxonomy or in cck text field... what is better?

1. what is the best way to do a form dropdown  options of known-non changing options? like choose color: 
   red,green,blue.orange,gray ... should i use function and call to array? variable_set/get()? taxonomy vocab?
2. if i do a form for user that will not send to email its just need to add a node or stuff like that, is webform is a better alternative to the cck module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taxonomy does no caching afaik. To have adress etc info for user i 'd use profile module in core. (you use d6 or d7?) ,

to 1. simple list of non-chaning option which does not need to maintained elsewhere (db/file) you use cck text field and provide values to choose from.   Of course for many values, a cck taxonomy field is nice , because there are good import modules (taxonomy_csv and _xml)

question 2 i find hard to understand, pls elaborate a bit

Comment: i ment what are the diffrence between form core and webform module, what is the benefit of using webforms?

Answer (score 0):

Taxonomy isn't cached. It is also not really the best choice for entering addresses, CCK is perfect for that. If this data isn't going to be content Webform is ever perfecter :)

The benefit of Core+CCK for form based data collection is you can make nodes out of it, which means you can do anything that you would do with a node to the data you collect. Query, Display, Rules on it, whatever.

The advantage to Webform...is that that it's not turned into a node, as such it's more specialized for collection of information such as surveys, questionnaires, contact forms, etc and there are plenty of integration modules for webform to help you see/use your data in cool ways.

Re your questions:

1) CCK Text/Select - OR - the equivalent in Webform

2) Core & CCK, you cannot add site content with Webform

Cheers